# ClustalW on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, bioinformatics, biopython

In the biopython cookbook I couldn't find how to actually run `clustalw`. I have done what is on the cookbook but it is not running `clustalw` just printing

```
clustalw2 -infile=opuntia.fasta
```

Can anyone help me how to actually run `clustalw`?

Comment: Are you working through this section? http://biopython.org/DIST/docs/tutorial/Tutorial.html#htoc81

Comment: yes it was that section

Answer (score 1):

The section is copied from the BioPython documentation.

> >>> from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalwCommandline
> >>> cline = ClustalwCommandline("clustalw2", infile="opuntia.fasta")
> >>> print(cline)
>
> > clustalw2 -infile=opuntia.fasta

If you run

```
from Bio.Align.Applications import ClustalwCommandline
cline = ClustalwCommandline("clustalw2", infile="opuntia.fasta")
print(cline)
```

it will do 3 things

1. Import `ClustalwCommandline` module from BioPython
2. Create a `ClustalwCommandline` object
3. Print the object's string representation

If you want to execute the program, you would need to call the created object

```
stdout, stderr = cline()
```

which will then run the whole program with your provided parameters. The "normal" output will be found in `stdout` and all errors in `stderr`.

If get an error that the executable cannot be found, you either need to add the directory of `clustalw2` to your path or specify the full path (e.g. `cline = ClustalwCommandline("c:/users/gufran/programs/clustalw.exe", infile="opuntia.fasta"`).